# Отличие type() от isinstance()

Tags: python, объекты, типы-данных, синтаксис

В чём отличие между этими двумя функциями в `python`?

Comment: `type(True) == int` ложно, но `isinstance(True, int)` истинно

Comment: @andreymal Это можно как-то объяснить?

Comment: isinstance учитывает наследование классов, а класс bool наследуется от int

Comment: @andreymal ок, спс. если напишите ответ, зачту как правильный

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`isinstance` учитывает наследование, а `type` — нет.

***Пример:***

```py
class Bacon:
    pass


class Spam(Bacon):
    pass


x = Spam()

type(x) is Spam       # True
type(x) is Bacon      # False
isinstance(x, Spam)   # True
isinstance(x, Bacon)  # True
```

---

На практике данную особенность можно использовать, чтобы поддерживать полиморфизм.

Допустим, что функция должна менять поведение в зависимости от типа переданных данных. Например, по особому обрабатывать словари:

```py
def f(arg):
    if type(arg) is dict:
        print('Передан словарь!')
```

Если передать в неё обычный словарь, всё будет в порядке. Но если передать [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), всё сломается, несмотря на то, что `OrderedDict` поддерживает все необходимые методы.

Чтобы избежать этого и обрабатывать все типы, которые наследуются от `dict`, можно воспользоваться `isinstance`:

```py
if isinstance(arg, dict):
    print('Передан словарь!')
```

Comment: [ассоциация](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1549801/5741205)

Answer (score 0):

Хотя функция `type()` возвращает тип переданного аргумента, с ее помощью можно проверить, принадлежит ли аргумент тому или иному типу:

```
a = 10
b = [1,2,3]

type(a) == int      #True
type(b) == list     #True
type(a) == float    #False
```

В отличие от `type()`, функция `isinstance()` специально создана для проверки принадлежности данных определенному классу (типу данных):

```
isinstance(a,int)         #True
isinstance(b,list)        #True
isinstance(b,tuple)       #False

c = (4,5,6)
isinstance(c,tuple)       #True
```

Кроме того `isinstance()` по сравнению с `type()` позволяет проверить данное на принадлежность хотя бы одному типу из кортежа, переданного в качестве второго аргумента:

```
isinstance(a,(float, int, str))         #True
isinstance(a,(list, tuple, dict))       #False
```

Другое отличие `isinstance()`. Эта функция поддерживает наследование. Для `isinstance()` экземпляр производного класса также является экземпляром базового класса. Для `type()` это не так:

```
class A (list):
    pass

a = A()
type(a) == list     #False
type(a) == A        #True
isinstance(a,A)     #True
isinstance(a,list)  #True
```